Getting Kafka users info using kafka-configs
Hi am trying to get Kafka users list using the below command.   My Confluent version is 7.3.6
kafka-configs  --bootstrap-server broker-server:9092 --command-config client.properties \
--describe --entity-type users --entity-type clients

The command doesn't generate any error but there is no output either.
Also tried separately for users and clients
Whereas, if I run the similar command to get Topics info, I get the expected output
kafka-configs  --bootstrap-server broker-server:9092 --command-config client.properties \
--describe --entity-type topics

Ref: Confluent doc
From the doc :
If entity name is not specified, all entities of the specified type are described.
For example, to describe all users:
 bin/kafka-configs.sh  --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe \
 --entity-type users

Configs for user-principal 'user1'  are
producer_byte_rate=1024,consumer_byte_rate=2048,request_percentage=200 

Configs for default user-principal are
producer_byte_rate=1024,consumer_byte_rate=2048,request_percentage=200

Am I missing something when requesting information about the users or clients?  ( According to the attached link, the commands I have should be enough )

The docs show output after --add-config was used... And it lists configs that were added to entities, such as quotas for a user, not "user info"

@onecricketeer This is from the doc link above.   If entity name is not specified, all entities of the specified type are described. For example, to describe all users:
bin/kafka-configs.sh  --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe \   --entity-type users.        -------
Configs for user-principal 'user1' are producer_byte_rate=1024,consumer_byte_rate=2048,request_percentage=200 Configs for default user-principal are producer_byte_rate=1024,consumer_byte_rate=2048,request_percentage=200.       And it is working for topics the same way too

Right, so that's not describing "a user", but policies that were added for them. Did you add any policy configs for a specific user entity before describing them?

Btw, this isn't specific to Confluent https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#quotas

Not through command line.  Actually, my whole purpose of trying this is that I want to just get a list of all users defined for Confluent.  From your second comment, I do see it is generic to Kafka, I just added confluent, because that is the product we are using.    Is there any other command that will give me just the list of users.  I can do the decrypt from the properties file, but that gives the passwords also.  I just want the list of users.    Thanks

Kafka doesn't maintain any list of user names, that I'm aware of. For SASL authentication, there will be users in the server.properties file, but Zookeeper or Kerberos would typically be used for authorization / identification purposes
